# How do I reset Ruby and RubyGems / Path Variable? I have installed multiple versions while trying to fix and issue with Jekyll and Bundler

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, jekyll, bundler

I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.3 and cannot execute Jekyll commands. I suspect it's the result of too many versions  of Ruby / RubyGems installed and the conflicting paths I have created haphazardly, I'm pretty sure my path variable is completely messed up:

`echo $PATH` returns

`/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:export`

Here are the jekyll-related issues:

I receive `-bash: jekyll: command not found` when trying `jekyll serve` and when running `bundle exec jekyll serve`  it returns `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`.

I think another issue compounding this is that I installed jekyll globally when trying to update it. I notice that it pops up with all of its dependancies when running `gem list`

For reference - check out what I get when I run  `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.0 (2019-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin19]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/will/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/will/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-19
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /Users/will/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - export
```

Please help me get my system back to square one. I'm way in over my head and just want a do over.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to clear all those ruby paths from your PATH, remove every version of Ruby that you have installed and begin again with https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Install whatever versions of Ruby you need, and then use bundler to manage your gems https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/using-jekyll-with-bundler/

Invoke jekyll using `bundle exec jekyll` and you should be back in business.